# In Python3 how to send jsonp to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, mongodb, tornado

on this case I am using Tornado web
I just want to use some simple method to send json data from mongodb to javascript. 
and I just check some example on internet. I so confused 
finally I got result , Python 2 network allow you send message by string 
Python 3 must be byte

actually this original code from internet but write by python 2 , can't running on 
python3

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler  # this Tornado standard 

class JSONPHandler(RequestHandler):
    CALLBACK = 'jsonp' # define callback argument name <== this Javascript send to python callback name, java script send msg look like ?jsonp=?  check it 
    def finish(self, chunk=None):
        assert not self._finished
        if chunk: self.write(chunk)
        # get client callback method 
        print(type(self.CALLBACK)) <==show string class  
        callbacka = self.get_argument(self.CALLBACK)
        callback=bytes(callbacka+'(','utf-8') <== from this part to  new 
        # format output with jsonp
        self._write_buffer.insert(0,callback ) <== write some json head 
        self._write_buffer.append(bytes(')','utf-8'))  <== all msg must be bytes 
        super(JSONPHandler, self).finish()  <== must do finished step 
        # chunk must be None
```

Answer (score 1):

RequestHandler.write() and RequestHandler.finish() will convert the input to utf8 bytes for you. First, open the "mongo" shell and do:

```
> use test
switched to db test
> db.collection.insert({key: 'value'})
> db.collection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53232a5c8d12c74bb1a30bc1"), "key" : "value" }
```

Note the ObjectId generated here. Here's a code example using JSONP and PyMongo:

```
import bson.json_util
import pymongo
from bson import ObjectId
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, HTTPError, Application

db = pymongo.MongoClient().test


class JSONPHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        jsonp_callback_name = self.get_argument('jsonp')
        oid = self.get_argument('id')
        doc = db.collection.find_one(ObjectId(oid))
        if not doc:
            raise HTTPError(404)

        # bson.json_util handles nonstandard types like ObjectId.
        self.finish('%s(%s)' % (
            jsonp_callback_name,
            bson.json_util.dumps(doc)))

application = Application(
    [('/api', JSONPHandler)]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.listen(8888)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Now visit this URL, using the ObjectId generated from the "mongo" shell:

```
http://localhost:8888/api?jsonp=mycallback&id=53232a5c8d12c74bb1a30bc1
```

You should see output like so in your browser:

```
mycallback({"_id": {"$oid": "53232a5c8d12c74bb1a30bc1"}, "key": "value"})
```